# Filtering a list of HtmlElements based on a list of partial ids

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I've got an HtmlElementCollection and I want to use Linq to get a list of HtmlElements whose ids contain an id from another list.

So I've tried a couple of things none of which worked out. I get a list from the collection and try to filter it.

This is the list of partial ids. The element ids are distinct, and they have ids that correspond to this list plus some random-seeming numbers at the beginning.

```
string[] ids = {"btadminh_struct.description",
"thtmlb_textView_6",
"thtmlb_textView_7",
"btadminh_struct.object_id",
"thtmlb_textView_12",
"zbtsalesset_struct.po_number_sold",
"thtmlb_textView_17",
"thtmlb_textView_21",
"thtmlb_textView_24",
"btcustomerh_z_followupdate",
"thtmlb_textView_29",
"btrefobjmain_ibibase",
"btrefobjmain_ibinstancedesc",
"btpartnerserviceto_struct.description_name",
"btpartnerset_contact_name",
"zzericempresp_struct.partner_no",
"zbtcsrowner_struct.partner_no",
"btcustomerh_struct.zcomments",
"thtmlb_textView_19",
"btadminh_servicecontractdescr",
"btcustomerh_zcontracttype_descr",
"btrefobjmain_network_id",
"btrefobjmain_node_id",
"btrefobjmain_site_id"};
```

Element ids looks like this:

```
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_network_instance",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_network_id__items",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_network_id",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_network_id-btn",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_network_id__key",
"C29_W87_V88_thtmlb_label_2",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_service_id__items",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_service_id",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_service_id-btn",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_service_id__key",
"C29_W87_V88_thtmlb_label_3",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_networkadap_id__items",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_networkadap_id",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_networkadap_id-btn",
"C29_W87_V88_btrefobjmain_networkadap_id__key",
```

So I've put my collection into a List that I can query.

```
var elems = doc.All.Cast<HtmlElement>();
```

I've tried different approaches, none of which are quite working. I'd also like to use Linq and avoid an ugly 2-D foreach loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so something like `elems.Where(x => ids.Any(id => x.ID.Contains(id)))`

What this is doing is going through each item in elems (your html element list) and then going through each id in your id collection and if any match, then it will return that element.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. For the purpose of parsing web elements, to avoid a NullReferenceException I added a condition so my complete statement is:
var elems = doc.All.Cast<HtmlElement>().Where(x => ids.Any(id => (x.Id != null) && (x.Id.Contains(id)))).ToList();

Comment: You could improve performance a lot by moving the null check earlier (on big lists)... `doc.All.Case<HtmlElement>().Where(x => x.Id != null).Where(x => ids.Any(id => x.Id.Contains(id)))`. Or just move the null check to before the `Any` call and that'll work too

Comment: I did that earlier but thought it would be worse because of calling where twice. But I suppose narrowing down the list first would be ideal?

Comment: Yes, you only need to do it once and it better to filter down the list before you do the `Any` calls because that is an additional loop