# Join an array of string with the result of an existing linq statement

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, dictionary

As a follow up to my last question here:
[Filtering a list of HtmlElements based on a list of partial ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762879/filtering-a-list-of-htmlelements-based-on-a-list-of-partial-ids/21762958?noredirect=1#comment32933850_21762958)

I need to take this statement:

```
doc.All.Cast<HtmlElement>()
    .Where(x => x.Id != null)
    .Where(x => ids
        .Any(id => x.Id.Contains(id))).ToList();
```

and join it with an array of strings called fields. Assuming the array and list will have the same amount of elements each and line up correctly. I tried using Zip() but thought I might need to use an additional linq statement to make it work.

Comment: so what do you want, a `Dictionary<string,string>` or a `List` of custom type?

Comment: Oops, sorry for leaving that out. Yes I'm aiming to get a Dictionary<string,string>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `fieldList[0]` and `IdList[0]` corresponding to each other, you can do the following:

```
var IdList = doc.All.Cast<HtmlElement>()
            .Where(x => x.Id != null)
            .Where(x => ids
            .Any(id => x.Id.Contains(id))).ToList();

var resultList = fieldList 
             .Select( (item, index) => new { Field = item, Id = IdList[index] })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Field);
```

Comment: By any chance, can this be done in one linq statement? So instead of putting the first statement into a list, use ToDictionary(fields, x.InnerText), where fields is an array of string, x is an HtmlElement. Or something to that effect?

Comment: Why `Select` and not a simple `Zip`?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned it already, you can use `Enumerable.Join`:

```
var joined = from id in fields
             join ele in elements on id equals ele.Id
             select new { Element = ele, ID = id };
var dict = joined.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x.Element);
```

I've presumed that you want to join them via ID. I've also presumed that the `string[]` contains only unique ID's.  Otherwise you need to use `Distinct`.

Comment: It seems fields is a `List<string>`

Comment: No, I don't want to join them by id. The ids aren't very readable (you can see the link I provided for an idea of what they look like). Assuming same amount of elements in the array and list, I tried zipping them but couldn't get that working. I just want them joined where the array of strings becomes the ids of the dictionary and the inner text of each HtmlElement becomes the value. (Hope that makes it clearer).

Comment: @TimSchmelter doesn't matter still there is no Id property exists

Comment: So currently the query produces a list, and fields is a string[].