# To click a button with the class having many of the same class

Tags: c#

When to click a button on a web page in a `WebBrowser`, I have to do it by the element class with the following code :

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = WebBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
 {
   if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "button color")
    {
       element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
 }
```

I want to click on the button that has the class `button color` but are twelve buttons with the same class, and I want to simulate the click on the first one only.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why do you have twelve buttons with the same class name? If you want it to only invoke the click on the first button found then you can add a `break;` in your foreach loop after the `InvokeMember` call.

Comment: the second answer does not work
and if to give the second or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to move my comments to be an answer. Since juansanchez1993 wanted to only simulate the click on the first button only out of the twelve that have the same class name, then the simple solution was to add a `break` in the `foreach` loop after the `InvokeMember` was called for the button. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = WebBrowser1.Document.All;

foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "button color")
    {
       element.InvokeMember("click");
       break; //Add the break after the InvokeMember is called to only invoke the 1st button click.
    }
}
```

Here is what I mean in my comments by using `System.Linq` to call a specific class button:

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = WebBrowser1.Document.All.Where(e => e.GetAttribute("className") == "button color") as HtmlElementCollection;

classButton[index].InvokeMember("click");
```

Disclaimer: I never used `HtmlElementCollection` before so be sure to add some comments if you are having an issue with this.

Comment: and if to give the second or somewhere else?

Comment: error http://i.imgur.com/lC0bzAF.png Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection' no contiene una definición de 'Where' ni se encontró ningún método de extensión 'Where' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection' (¿falta una directiva de uso o una referencia de ensamblado?) 
Error 2 El nombre 'index' no existe en el contexto actual              I put using System.Linq;

Comment: the second answer does not work
and if to give the second or somewhere else?

Comment: are you able to cast HtmlElementCollection to a `List<HtmlElement>`? I'm 100% sure that `List<T>` can use the `Where` LINQ method. I wasn't sure about the `HtmlElementCollection` because I never used it before. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762879/filtering-a-list-of-htmlelements-based-on-a-list-of-partial-ids) might be helpful to you though.

Comment: I think going well but not well raised their code, a shame that I did not know much about it